# finding difference in days between two dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to know the difference in days between the following dates...can anyone provide inputs on how to achieve this?

```
CR created date
2013-11-01
Current date
2013-11-09 18:17:53.196126
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module.  If you have a `datetime.datetime` object `A`, and a `datetime.date` object `B`, the difference is:

```
A.date() - B
```

Try it ;-)

Example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> A = datetime.strptime("2013-11-09 18:17:53.196126", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> B = date(*map(int, "2013-11-01".split("-")))
>>> print A
2013-11-09 18:17:53.196126
>>> print B
2013-11-01
>>> print A.date() - B
8 days, 0:00:00
```

Comment: ,with the above example...I tried it didnt work..did it work for you?

Comment: @user2955256, sorry, I have no idea what you tried. I made an edit to show how it works.

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'` on Python 2

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, did you make `B` a `datetime` object instead of a `date` object?  The example code obviously subtracts a `date` from a `date`, so couldn't produce the msg you gave.

Comment: Understood - I think it's unfortunate that `datetime.date` doesn't support a stripped-down `strptime`.  The `*map(int, ... .split(...` dance is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to change the input to a type that python knows - [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html). Then use the builtin functions.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> A = datetime.strptime('2013-11-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> A
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>> B = datetime.strptime('2013-11-09 18:17:53.196126', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> B
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 9, 18, 17, 53, 196126)
>>> diff = B - A
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(8, 65873, 196126)
>>> diff.total_seconds()
757073.196126
>>> diff.total_seconds() / (60 * 60 * 24)
8.762421251458333
```

Comment: to get full days as an integer: `diff.days`